# For Loop Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

Why do I get this as a result to this code?

**CODE**

```
ids = 0;
for (NSString *s in golferThreeIconCounter) {
    ids++;
    NSLog(@"%i", ids);
}
```

**RESULT**

```
2012-05-24 16:30:35.194 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 4
2012-05-24 16:30:35.196 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 8
2012-05-24 16:30:35.196 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 12
2012-05-24 16:30:35.197 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 16
2012-05-24 16:30:35.197 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 20
2012-05-24 16:30:35.198 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 24
2012-05-24 16:30:35.199 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 28
2012-05-24 16:30:35.199 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 32
2012-05-24 16:30:35.200 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 36
2012-05-24 16:30:35.200 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 40
2012-05-24 16:30:35.201 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 44
2012-05-24 16:30:35.201 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 48
2012-05-24 16:30:35.202 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 52
2012-05-24 16:30:35.202 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 56
2012-05-24 16:30:35.203 Dot Golf Scoring[673:f803] 60
```

It makes absolutely no sense to me why ids goes up 4 times instead of just once...

Comment: What kind of variable is `ids`?  You NSLog it as an integer, but I don't see the variable declaration.

Comment: What is the definition of ids?  (data type?)

Comment: Must be a pointer type, no?

Comment: its an int being declaired like this... int *ids;

Comment: declare it like this `NSInteger ids = 0`

Comment: `int` doesn't get declared like that. I don't exactly know *why* so I'll leave that to a more qualified answerer.

Comment: Then it's a "pointer" to an int, not an int. So you are incrementing a pointer producing the results above.

Comment: The problem is Obj-C has "primitive types" and "object types" sort of like Java. Object type variables are declared using pointers, hence they all contain the `*`, for example `NSObject*` and `NSString*`. When dealing with primitive types (int, char, NSInteger) leave out the *

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you declare an int, you do not add `*`: it's not an `<id>` type. What you have is a *pointer* to an `int`; on a 32-bit platform it increments by 4.

```
int ids = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the "position" count of a pointer which is referenced in an array.

So let me try to clarify that.

A pointer is four bytes. In this case you have an array of pointers. So when you loop over you are printing the int value of the index of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment by using: `*ids++` since you've declared it as a reference.  Or else you need to declare it as a primitive variable: `int ids = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
int ids = 0;
for (NSString *s in golferThreeIconCounter) {
    ids++;
    NSLog(@"%i", ids);
}
```

Try this. You never declared the type of variable that `ids` is.